# Is it safe to write files in mode os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY?

Tags: go

I have a Go function that appends a line to a file:

```
func AppendLine(p string, s string) error {
    f, err := os.OpenFile(p, os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, 0600)
    defer f.Close()

    if err != nil {
        return errors.WithStack(err)
    }

    _, err = f.WriteString(s + "\n")
    return errors.WithStack(err)
}
```

I'm wondering if the flags `os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY` make this a safe operation. Is there a guarantee that no matter what happens (even if the process gets shut off in the middle of writing) the existing file contents cannot be deleted?

Comment: That's a question for the operating system.

Comment: Can you give some advice on how I should reason about this? I am running on Ubuntu.

Comment: each of those flags resolves down to having its own unique single bit on ... so when they are OR'd together the final result combination is legit ... for example one flag may have value 01000000  and another may resolve down to binary value 00010000  so when the are OR'd the final resulting settings is 01010000

Comment: @rampatowl: Read the Linux Programmer's Manual: `man 2 open`. Read the POSIX specification: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/functions/open.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

os package is a wrapper around systems calls so you have guarantees provided by operation system. In this case linux OS guarantees that file opened with O_APPEND flag would be processed atomically http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html